# How to link OpenCV with MATLAB for macOS

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, clang, mex

I am trying to run C++ code that uses the OpenCV  library with MATLAB and `mex` command (the code already has a `mexFunction`).

I already have the OpenCV library installed, I used it with Python before. I assume that it should work for running C++ code. I am running this command to compile the code on MATLAB:

```
mex -setup
mex fileName.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/
```

and I also tried:

```
mex fileName.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include/ -llibopencv_core
```

But I got different errors and it does not compile successfully, such as:

> error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to
> 'unsigned long' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
>
> note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
> const long unsigned int

I feel that there is something wrong with linking.
How can I link OpenCV with MATLAB to run C++ code using the Clang compiler on macOS?

in c++ code:
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

and opencv2 is inside -I/usr/local/include/

inside /usr/local/lib , I can only find these
[opencv libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFNId.png)

Comment: A narrowing cast is only an error if you set up your compiler to error instead of warn. You are likely missing a `-lopencv` or some such in your compile command. More information is needed.

Comment: you tried opencv with python but how did you install opencv ?

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for replying, I tried to add -lopencv but still have the error, 
yes I believe that I missed something but what it is?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk  I used pip install opencv-python as far as I remeber

Comment: the libraries u installed with pip only available for python. You can not use them with c++.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, I install opencv from brew that should work for c++ from the tutorial but still have the same error

Comment: Please search well then asking the question. The comments are meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The fix was by using the **correct paths** to the opencv library and Include folder, since I have on my computer several files for opencv that are installed using pip for python projects, I change the path to opencv folder that installed by brew.
2- I also added all the needed -l files not only
-llibopencv_core. By the way, I needed to remove (lib) form llibopencv_core so it becomes like this **-lopencv_core** so the compiler (clang) can see it.

3- Finally, to silent the narrowing error, I made some changes on types of the variable to make it consistence and that's all, (however, some compilers consider it as warning and can work fine without any changes).